# find a lastname from a array of object in javascript it doesn't return valid output

Tags: javascript, oop

I tried to find a lastname from a array of object in javascript, but I find it very hard. My code is as follows and it doesn't return any output.

```
The "lastName"s array should be sorted in alphabetical order

Function to return a Promise object and not a String or Array
```

it can be multiple ans or a array of object

```
function getLastNames(firstName, people) {


    return new Promise(function (myResolve, myReject) {

        for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
            if (people.find(people.firstName == firstName) ) {
                
                myResolve(people.lastName(firstName));
                
            }
        }
        myReject("Invalid");





    });

}

module.exports = getLastNames;
```

Comment: [tag:C++]??? Are you sure?

Comment: Please consult the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to properly format your code. Also, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your question to show a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: sent me error as well as your array of object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function getLastNames(firstName, people) {

  return new Promise(function (Resolve, Reject) {
      for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
          if (people.find(()=>people[i].firstName == firstName) ) {  
              Resolve(people[i].lastName);      
          }
      }
      Reject("Invalid");
  });
  }

let people=[{firstName:"Satish", lastName:"kumar"},{firstName:"Raja", lastName:"kumar"} ] 
let firstName="Satish"
  getLastNames(firstName, people).then(res=>console.log("res",res)).catch(err=>console.log("err", err))
```

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer please upvote me

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be "eq" or "==" or something instead of "=" ?

also not sure what the point of people.lastName(firstName) is..  it's not just people.lastname ?

Comment: thanks for this i forgot about it but it give me the same error